# What's this chair design name?

Tags: technique-identification, leather

I've seen this chair in many places, for instance

as sold in Brazil (under the name "Old Jones"):
[image: 1] [image: 2]

as sold in UK ("Butler Milo Iron & Leather Accent Chair"):
[image: 3]

(there are other places as well)

It looks like a fairly common design, though I can't find who invented it not when nor what it was named.

I'll try to describe it briefly: an iron hoop at - maybe - 45º, with leather stapled over/around the upper and lower sections of it (though not always a single piece of leather), raised from the floor by hairpin legs (the same iron thickness of the iron hoop); the leather pieces are kept streched by another part of the iron structure that lies beneath the hoop; all the iron structure is painted (usually black) and are mostly naked (the only covered parts are the upper and lower sections of the hoop); particularily the naked sections of the hoop serve as armrests.

(I can't create tags yet, but I would like to tag it "design-identification", "designer-identification", "chair", "armchair", "furniture")

Comment: Try looking at Charles Eames designs . He developed a few.

Comment: Looks easy to construct, but painful in which to sit! I imagine that the top of the hoop hits the back in a bad way, and the bottom of the hoop cuts off leg circulation after sitting for a while.  But visually, I do find the lines appealing from certain angles.

Answer (score 2):

After a little research, I found what may be the origin of the design, based on [Raymond Loewy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Loewy)'s [Hoop Chair](https://penccil.com/museum.php?p=853008315981).

[image]